# .htaccess rule to remove from URL if present?

Tags: .htaccess, url

We are having a problem with one of our websites, sometimes we see a long url that is not related to any real page on our site. For example the URL should be

```
https://example.com/browse
```

But one time in a hundred we get this

```
https://example.com/index.php/module/action/param1/static/PFBC/js/jquery/rss/signup/static/js/jquery/templates/themes/love/img/icon/asset/css/legal/user/album/tipocorneo/me/browse
```

Its not always the same URL it changes from time to time but my question is this... Is there a rewrite rule we could use that simply removes the extra part of the URL if its present?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>
    Options +FollowSymLinks

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_flag allow_url_include Off
    php_flag expose_php Off
</IfModule>

### Security and Spam ###

# Protect the repository directory
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteRule "(^|/)\.git" - [F,L]
</IfModule>

ServerSignature Off

# Deny access to all CGI, Perl, Python, Bash, SQL, Template, INI configuration, cache, log, temporary and text files
<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|pl|py|sh|bash|sql|tpl|ini|cache|log|tmp|txt)$">
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all denied
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

# Leave open the humans.txt and robots.txt file
<FilesMatch "humans\.txt|robots\.txt">
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all granted
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

# Deny access for "composer.json"
<FilesMatch "composer\.json|sample\.htaccess">
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all denied
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

# Prevent .htaccess/.htpasswd from being downloaded
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all denied
    </IfModule>
</Files>

<Limit GET POST PUT DELETE HEAD>
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        <RequireAll>
            Require all granted
            Require not env bad_bot
        </RequireAll>
    </IfModule>
</Limit>

ErrorDocument 400 /error/http/index?code=400
ErrorDocument 401 /error/http/index?code=401
ErrorDocument 402 /error/http/index?code=402
ErrorDocument 403 /error/http/index?code=403
ErrorDocument 404 /error
ErrorDocument 405 /error/http/index?code=405
ErrorDocument 500 /error/http/index?code=500
ErrorDocument 501 /error/http/index?code=501
ErrorDocument 502 /error/http/index?code=502
ErrorDocument 504 /error/http/index?code=504
ErrorDocument 505 /error/http/index?code=505

# URL Rewrite
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_env.c>
        # Tell PHP that the mod_rewrite module is ENABLED.
        SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
    </IfModule>

    # Uncomment the following only if HTTPS is enabled. HSTS header increases security of your website & SEO
    # <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; preload" env=HTTPS
    # </IfModule>

    # Remove www subdomain in the URL
    # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Force the URL to be https (only if you have an SSL certificate). May not be necessary if HSTS is enabled
    # RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]

    # Start Bad Bot Prvention
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^BackWeb [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Bandit [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^BatchFTP [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Buddy [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Collector [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Copier [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Download\Wonder [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Downloader [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^LinkWalker [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^BlackWidow [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Bot\ mailto:craftbot@yahoo.com [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ChinaClaw [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Custo [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^DISCo [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Download\ Demon [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^eCatch [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EirGrabber [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailSiphon [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailWolf [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailCollector [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Crescent [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^CherryPicker [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Express\ WebPictures [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ExtractorPro [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EyeNetIE [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^FlashGet [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GetRight [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GetWeb! [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Go!Zilla [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^gotit [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Go-Ahead-Got-It [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GrabNet [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Grafula [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^HMView [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} HTTrack [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Image\ Stripper [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Image\ Sucker [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Indy\ Library [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^InterGET [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Internet\ Ninja [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^JetCar [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^JOC\ Web\ Spider [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^larbin [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^libghttp [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^LeechFTP [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mass\ Downloader [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^MIDown\ tool [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mister\ PiX [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Navroad [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NearSite [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetAnts [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetSpider [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Net\ Vampire [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetZIP [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Octopus [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Offline\ Explorer [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Offline\ Navigator [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^PageGrabber [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Papa\ Foto [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^pavuk [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^pcBrowser [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Pockey [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Pump [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^RealDownload [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ReGet [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SiteSnagger [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SmartDownload [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SuperBot [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SuperHTTP [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Surfbot [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^tAkeOut [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Teleport\ Pro [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^VoidEYE [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Web\ Image\ Collector [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Web\ Sucker [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebAuto [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebCopier [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebFetch [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebGo\ IS [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebLeacher [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebReaper [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebSauger [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Website\ eXtractor [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Website\ Quester [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebStripper [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebWhacker [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebZIP [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Wget [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Widow [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WWWOFFLE [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Xaldon\ WebSpider [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Zeus
    RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
    # End Bad Bot Prevention
</IfModule>

# Modify Headers
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Cache files
    <FilesMatch "\.(jpe?g|png|gif|ico|webp|swf|mp3|mp4|flv|webm|pdf)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "public"
        Header set Expires "Mon, 20 Apr 2060 20:00:00 GMT"
        Header unset Last-Modified
    </FilesMatch>

    # Cache JavaScript & CSS
    <FilesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "public"
        Header set Expires "Mon, 20 Apr 2060 20:00:00 GMT"
        Header unset Last-Modified
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# Compress files
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    # Insert filter
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
        # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
        # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
        BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
        # Don't compress images/archives/music/video/etc
        SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
        SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:exe|t?gz|zip|bz2|sit|rar)$ no-gzip dont-vary
        SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:avi|mov|mp3|mp4|rm|flv|swf|mp?g)$ no-gzip dont-vary
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

# Enable Expirations
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
    # expire images/css/js/swf files after a month in the client's cache
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 31 days"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 31 days"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 31 days"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 31 days"
    ExpiresByType application/x-gzip "access plus 31 days"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 31 days"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 31 days"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 31 days"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 31 days"
    ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon "access plus 31 days"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>

# For the videos extensions
#AddType video/ogg .ogg
AddType video/webm .webm
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType application/rss+xml .xml
```

Comment: How do you currently route URLs in `.htaccess`? (What do you currently have in `.htaccess`? - Please add this to your question.) Are you using path-info to route URLs? Presumably `index.php` is a valid file? What response is this erroneous URL returning? Have you confirmed that this is not the result of an error on your site? Where do these requests originate from?

Comment: You want a fallback rule at the end of your rewriting rule set which catches all request not yet handled.

Comment: Yes index.php is a valid file and returns 404 page not found. I will add htaccess file to question.

Comment: Yes a fall back is the sort of idea I was thinking.

Comment: "remove extra part" - what do you mean exactly? Everything in the URL-path before the final path segment? Although a 404 is arguably the preferred response for such a malformed request? If you have _confirmed_ that this is not a result of a missconfiguration on your site (which you must resolve first) then this could even be a malicious request. (Although it does kinda look like a missconfiguration though?) And where do these requests originate - that should give you a big clue as to the cause?

Comment: The extra part being the added    index.php/module/action/param1/static/PFBC/js/jquery/rss/signup/static/js/jquery/templates/themes/love/img/icon/asset/css/legal/user/album/tipocorneo/me/

Comment: Yes configuration seemed to be the likely answer but we have tried everything we can think of. Funny thing is this site ran perfect for 8wks with no problem we moved to a dedicated server and it started so yes server config is the cause but we cant seem to find exactly what is causing it.

Comment: "so yes server config is the cause" - "server config" is _unlikely_ the cause here, it is far more likely to be something in your site/application logic.

Answer (score 1):

To redirect `/index.php/foo/bar/baz/something` to `/something` then you can do something like the following at the very top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php/[\w/]+/([\w]+)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=302,L]
```

The shorthand character class `\w` matches word characters (`a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` and `_`) so matches the example URL given.

This redirect also canonicalises the scheme, so place this directive *before* the HTTP to HTTPS redirect to avoid a 2nd redirect when requesting HTTP.

However, a URL of this nature does suggest a missconfiguration in your site/application. Although, it could also be a malicious request (although the non-spam-like content in the URL does not really suggest that).

You should check the `Referer` in your server's access log for these requests, which should give you a clue as to their origin.

Comment: I got very close to solving this myself but after hours of trail and error I finally managed to write a rule that removed the segments on a rule tester but once applied to the .htaccess file the server just hung. I later found somebody online who helped write this (I will add his name and the rule later). But like a few of you have said all I could think was misconfiguration. I spent almost 10hrs searching for this and finally found the problem... It was down to a rss cache function it was getting confused due to hosting providers inode limitations which explains why it only happens sometimes

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct answer it was written by donatJ

```
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^index\.php/module/action/param1/.*/(.*+)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```